# Handling OpenStreetMap 64-bit identifiers correctly in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, 64bit

An OpenStreetMap wiki states, "QGIS will no longer be usable with newer OSM data spreading all over the world" because it's "incompatible with OSM data containing 64-bit Identifiers."[1]  The wiki claims "QGIS may still be used for retrieving data however it is possible for the geometries to look very incorrect, with ways mixing old nodes below the 32-bit limit and new nodes not found after they are truncated to 32-bit or at wrong positions: data retrieval may unpredicatably give ***inconsistent results*** at any time."[2]

Does QGIS support 64 bit identifiers?

Has this been updated with the newer QGIS version, is it currently being updated, or is there some work-around to avoid issues with newer data?

[1] http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/64-bit_Identifiers
[2] http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/QGIS

Comment: The bug (https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10790) is still open.

Comment: The fact that no-one was assigned, or self-assigned, to fix this bug - as visible in the issue tracker - probably means its going to take even considerably longer than the two years it has been open now...

Comment: The OSM wiki page on QGIS has been in needing attention for a while. That warning in particular until recently was suggesting that QGIS was entirely incomparable with OSM data - clearly not the case. Whatever the facts I think the warning was written initially/primarily to warn people off using QGIS as one of the editors for contributing to OSM (in case it damaged the data). Of course many people use OSM data with QGIS one way or another. I had a go at lessening the anti-QGIS style of this warning some time ago but don't know enough about the issue. Keen to see someone help improve this.

Comment: The link for the bug is now https://issues.qgis.org/issues/10790 and the bug is in the plugin, not in QGIS.

Answer (score 6):

As the OSM wiki page that you linked states, the old
OpenStreetMap Plugin is obsolete and has been replaced by the  QuickOSM
plugin that can read (but not write) data from OSM. QuickOSM handles 64bit identifiers correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The 3-part importer under `Vector -> Openstreetmap` has been critized much, and will most probably be discontinued. The data is stored in a spatialite database, but can not be retrieved correctly in QGIS. You can however use part 1 (retrieve data from the OSM server), and load the file with `Add Vector layer` or the QuickOSM plugin into QGIS. The QuickOSM plugin is able to store all tags into separate columns, while you need to edit the `osmconf.ini` file manually for `Add vector layer` to get special tags.

The ticket 10790 adresses the 32-bit-**unsigned**-limit for node numbers that was reached in July 2016.

The old OSM plugin has been deprecated long before that, and suffered the 32-bit-**signed**-limit from 2013.

Both import methods skip line and polygon features that include nodes with higher numbers, making the tool useless.

You may find further discussions at https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8878, https://hub.qgis.org/issues/12727 and http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Suggestion-Remove-Vector-Openstreetmap-tool-from-QGIS-2-12-td5226614.html

`Add Vector layer` and the `QuickOSM` plugin work far better.

Comment: Could you chime in on the discussion in http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Suggestion-Remove-Vector-Openstreetmap-tool-from-QGIS-2-12-td5226614.html?

Comment: No problem, you can use Nabble like a forum and reply to any mail there

Comment: I opened a new discussion at http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Deprecation-of-the-Vector-OpenStreetMap-Importer-td5286805.html

Answer (score 1):

A work-around is to open OSM data through GDAL with Add vector layer... It that case this driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html will handle the data. You must download OSM data by other means (from some service with direct calls or from the extracts of Geofabrik etc.) and save the result to file first. GDAL also creates layers in different way and you must also read how osmconf.ini file works.